# Put minimum number value on innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Oké guys I'm working on a project where i got:

```
<select class="select2" id="product1" onchange="shopCalculate(this.value)." >
                              <option value="4.1" >Option 1</option>
                              <option value="4">Option 2</option>
                              <option value="3.9">Option 3</option>
                              <option value="3.8">Option 4</option>
                              <option value="3.75">Option 5</option>
                            </optgroup>
                              <option value="3.7">Option 6</option>
                              <option value="3.65">Option 7</option>
                              <option value="3.6">Option 8</option>
                              <option value="3.5">Option 9</option>
                              <option value="3.5">Option 10</option>
                            </optgroup>
                              <option value="3.5">Option 11</option>
                              <option value="3.3">Option 12</option>
                              <option value="3.1">Option 13</option>
                              <option value="2.9">Option 14</option>
                              <option value="2.7">Option 15</option>
                            </optgroup>
                              <option value="2.5">Option 16</option>
                              <option value="2.3">Option 17</option>
                              <option value="2.1">Option 18</option>
                              <option value="1.9">Option 19</option>
                              <option value="1.7">Option 20</option>
                            </optgroup>

                          </select>

          <ul>
            <li><strong class="bg-info"><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></strong></li>

            <li id="product_type"></li>
            <li id="product_sort"></li>
            <li id="product_tag"></li>

      <hr/>
            <li>
              <strong>
                Total cost: <span id="cost_eur">€0.00 </span> (<span id="cost_usd" class="small">$0.00</span>)
              </strong>
            </li>
           </ul>
      <hr/>

function shopCalculate(a) {
    var product1 = $('select[id=product_1]').val();
    cost_eur.innerHTML = "€" + (a - product1).toFixed(2);
    cost_usd.innerHTML = "$" + (a - product1 * 1.13 ).toFixed(2);
  }
```

This puts the result to cost_eur and cost_usd, but the total value gets negative (i.e < 0) on some occasions. **What i want is to put a standard number like 10 if the value gets < 10.** how do i do that since innerHTML brings out a string.
I've tried some things with parseFloat() but obviously that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `.val()` to `.text()`

Comment: Sorry my  bad i forgot an important part of the code which got you on the wrong path. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more function to calculate the total amount and pass it like this. Hope it helps.

```
function calculateTotalAmt(a, currencyType) {
    var totalAmt;
    var product1 = $('select[id=product_1]').val();
    if(currencyType == 'euro') {
        totalAmt = (a - product1).toFixed(2);
    } else if(currencyType == 'usd') {
        totalAmt = (a - product1 * 1.13 ).toFixed(2); 
    }
    if(totalAmt != undefined && totalAmt < 10)
        totalAmt = 10;
    return totalAmt;
}

function divCalculate(a) {     
    cost_eur.innerHTML = "€" + calculateTotalAmt(a,'euro');
    cost_usd.innerHTML = "$" + calculateTotalAmt(a,'usd');
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, i don't quite understand where you get the 'euro' and 'usd' variables, and to be a little bit more clear on my side. I need both the values of Euro and Dollar to be printed not one or the other.

Comment: I have written a function which takes the type of currency. Based on the type of currency, it computes the total Amount. I have used the same computation logic in this function as provided in your code. You can add more currency type in future, so i am specifically passing the currency types.